# Most effective way to detect a browser in PHP?

Tags: php, search

I am writing an ad manager that log every time a user clicks on a link. How can I modify these links to stop search engines from crawling my site?  I know, the most obvious one would be with a "nofollow" links, but how do I stop others?  Is there perhaps a list of search engines ips or some other way to stop them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP detect a browser with `get_browser`

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Stop search engines from crawling your site with a robots.txt exclusion file:

http://antezeta.com/news/avoid-search-engine-indexing

Comment: +1 for recommending `robots.txt`.